# C# CSCore no sound from mp3 file

Tags: c#, .net, cscore

Using the CSCore library, I wrote the code for playing an mp3 file in the class `BGM` in a seperate file called `BGM.cs` and the method for playback is `BGM.Play("file directory");`, which is called in the Form. But somehow I can't manage to get any sound out of it. I've already checked volume, codec and output, and I can't think of anything else that might cause this problem.

This is the code of the class file:

```
public class BGM
{
    public static void Play(string file)
    {
        using (IWaveSource soundSource = GetSoundSource(file))
        {
            using (ISoundOut soundOut = GetSoundOut())
            {
                soundOut.Initialize(soundSource);
                soundOut.Volume = 0.8f;
                soundOut.Play();
            }
        }
    }
    private static ISoundOut GetSoundOut()
    {
        if (WasapiOut.IsSupportedOnCurrentPlatform)
            return new WasapiOut();
        else
            return new DirectSoundOut();
    }
    private static IWaveSource GetSoundSource(string file)
    {
        return CodecFactory.Instance.GetCodec(file);
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

There are actually a couple reasons why your mp3 isn't playing.

The first reason is you haven't specified a device for the sound to play on. The code below gets the first device that can render sound, but that won't always be correct if the user has multiple devices attached to their computer. You'll have to handle that appropriately. The device has to be set on the `WasapiOut` object.

The second reason is your use of `using` statements in your `Play` method. While it's always a good idea to clean up objects that implement `IDisposable`, you can't always do so immediately. In this case, `soundOut.Play()` is not a blocking method, which meant that control was exiting the method immediately, causing `Dispose()` to be called on `soundOut` and `soundSource`. This meant that the sound would effectively never be played (maybe it would start for a short moment, but not enough to really hear it). Essentially, you need to hold onto the references and only dispose of them once playback is complete.

Have a look at the [AudioPlayerSample](https://github.com/filoe/cscore/tree/master/Samples/AudioPlayerSample) for an idea on how to implement a complete solution. My code should get you started.

```
void Main()
{
    using(var player = new BGM(@"D:\Test.mp3"))
    {
        player.Play();

        // TODO: Need to wait here in order for playback to complete
        // Otherwise, you need to hold onto the player reference and dispose of it later
        Console.ReadLine();
    }
}

public class BGM : IDisposable
{
    private bool _isDisposed = false;
    private ISoundOut _soundOut;
    private IWaveSource _soundSource;

    public BGM(string file)
    {
        _soundSource = CodecFactory.Instance.GetCodec(file);
        _soundOut = GetSoundOut();
        _soundOut.Initialize(_soundSource);
    }

    public void Play()
    {
        if(_soundOut != null)
        {
            _soundOut.Volume = 0.8f;
            _soundOut.Play();
        }
    }

    public void Stop()
    {
        if(_soundOut != null)
        {
            _soundOut.Stop();
        }
    }

    private static ISoundOut GetSoundOut()
    {
        if (WasapiOut.IsSupportedOnCurrentPlatform)
        {
            return new WasapiOut
            {
                Device = GetDevice()
            };
        }

        return new DirectSoundOut();
    }

    private static IWaveSource GetSoundSource(string file)
    {
        return CodecFactory.Instance.GetCodec(file);
    }

    public static MMDevice GetDevice()
    {
        using(var mmdeviceEnumerator = new MMDeviceEnumerator())
        {
            using(var mmdeviceCollection = mmdeviceEnumerator.EnumAudioEndpoints(DataFlow.Render, DeviceState.Active))
            {
                // This uses the first device, but that isn't what you necessarily want
                return mmdeviceCollection.First();
            }
        }
    }

    protected virtual void Dispose(bool disposing)
    {
        if (!_isDisposed)
        {
            if (disposing)
            {
                if(_soundOut != null)
                {
                    _soundOut.Dispose();
                }

                if(_soundSource != null)
                {
                    _soundSource.Dispose();
                }
            }

            _isDisposed = true;
        }
    }

    public void Dispose()
    {
        Dispose(true);
    }
}
```